# Guess what I am!

Tags: riddle

I am nothing right now, only a blocker for the others and a sitting duck to those with power.

One day however, I will step to their side and rise to the top, given the opportunity.

What am I?

(feedback for first puzzle appreciated)

*seems too broad so here's a hint which will probably make it 10x easier...*

> The object will start out in a row of its own kind

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> a pawn in the game of chess.

I am nothing right now, only a blocker for the others and a sitting duck to those with power.

> Pawns start out with very little ability, but forming a row in front of all the pieces with more power.

One day however, I will step to their side and rise to the top, given the opportunity.

> Pawns can capture other pieces by moving diagonally one square ("stepping to the side"); if they make it all the way to the opposite side of the board, they become a queen - arguably the most powerful!

Hint:

> Pawns start the game in a row of entirely pawns.

Comment: knew it would make it 10x easier... :D i'll give a grace period for any other creative answers like shiv has.

Comment: Yeah, it was the hint that gave it away.  I really like the wording of the original puzzle - it's really clever! - but I do think it opens it up to a lot of answers you may not have though of/ intended.  Thanks for sharing this great puzzle, though! :)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Nothing really gave the idea of board game... heh. For next time.

Answer (score 5):

You are:

> A bowling pin

I am nothing right now,

> The pin is worth zero points when standing

only a blocker for the others

> It blocks the path to the pins behind, making them harder to hit

and a sitting duck to those with power.

> A strong bowler will hit the pin hard with the ball.  It is not defended.

One day however, I will step to their side

> After pins have fallen they are pushed to the side.

and rise to the top, given the opportunity.

> The pins are then lifted up inside the machine, so that they can later be lowered back into place.

Hint:

> Pins start the game in rows.

Comment: This is a crazy analogy. He was right. This question gives way to many ideas... Haha. +1

Answer (score 3):

This is also my first answer, I think its:

> First sheet of notebook or newspaper

I am nothing right now

> It has no meaning when empty

only a blocker for the others and a sitting duck to those with power

> It blocks the others pages and usually people start with first paper

One day however, I will step to their side and rise to the top, given the opportunity.

> when its written or completed it gets stacked on top

Comment: Nice first answer! It's not what I had in mind though. I'll pop a hint in after a bit of time. Still, real nice guess!

Comment: Added a hint. Feel like it's too broad anyway lol